# Is there an equivalent to async.then (like in JS) for coroutines in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a variable isMoving and it should turn false when the corountine ends. Something like:

```cs
if (m_IsMoving == false){
    
    m_IsMoving = true;
    StartCoroutine(time_passed.Tweeng((time_Set_Movement) => 
        transform.position = time_Set_Movement,
        transform.position, 
        new Vector3(transform.position.x + positior.x,
        transform.position.y + positior.y, transform.position.z + positior.z) );
    // I am searching for some way to continue the coroutine with
    then{ m_IsMoving = false;}
    
}
```

is there an easy way to add something like that after the coroutine ends?

Comment: I highly recommend switching to this instead of coroutines https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask

Answer (score 0):

The most easy option is to change your value inside the coroutine. Smth like

```cs
private _someBool = false;

private void SomeMethod()
{
    StartCoroutine(CoSomeCoroutine());
}

private IEnumeratoe CoSomeCoroutine()
{
    _someBool = true;
    
    // do your stuff here
    
    _someBool = false;
}
```